# CStarRating On Click Save

Tags: php, yii

I am using CStarRating in my Yii project. What at present I have to do is set rating and then hit submit.This works very well but i want data in db to get update in single Go. I have tried various Ajax based tricks but I am new so I fail.

here is my existing code

```
  $this->widget('CStarRating',array(
           'model'=>$model,
           'attribute'=>'hotel_rating',
           'readOnly'=>FALSE,
        ));
```

I have tried following ajax one

```
  $this->widget('CStarRating',array(
        'name'=>'rating',
           'model'=>$model,
           'attribute'=>'hotel_rating',
        'callback'=>'
            function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "'.Yii::app()->createUrl('hotel/update').'",
                data: "id='.$model->id.'&rate=" + $(this).val(),

                success: function(msg){
                    alert("Sucess")
                    },
                error: function(xhr){
                alert("failure"+xhr.readyState+this.url)

                }
                    })}'
    ));
```

in controller I do but still unlucky

```
$model->hotel_rating = $_GET['rate'] 

$model->save()
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this).val()` in ajax call will return the rate value ?

Comment: I donot know but was done this way on many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller, I guess it should be `$model->hotel_rating = $_GET['rate']`, and similarly $_GET['id'] will return the id of the model.

Comment: sorry my mistake it is rate there

Comment: If you want to do updating on model, in update action, you need to find the model first with $_GET['id']. I have tested this widget with your code which works fine. What is your error exactly?

Comment: no error just values dont get updated :( please can you paste your code so that i can compare steps. I am new to Yii.I see Sucess appear but data does not get updated